# How to make orwhere laravel eloquent only work for some where clause?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```php
$list = xxxxx->where('speakers.status', '1')->where('speakers.id_user', '!=', Auth::id());
        
if ($search != '' && $search != null) {
    $list = $list->where('topiks.topik', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->orWhere('users.nama', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
}
```

How to make the `orWhere('users.nama', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')` only work for the `where('topiks.topik', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')` and not effect the first and second where  (`where('speakers.status', '1')` and `where('speakers.id_user', '!=', Auth::id()`)?

Because if the code is like above   the or where will effect the first and second where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you obtain the resulting SQL query, this is the result:

```php
$list = DB::connection('mysql')->table('xxxxx')->where('speakers.status', '1')->where('speakers.id_user', '!=', 1);
$list = $list->where('topiks.topik', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->orWhere('users.nama', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');

dump($list->toSql());

"select * from `xxxxx` where `speakers`.`status` = ? and `speakers`.`id_user`
 != ? and `topiks`.`topik` like ? or `users`.`nama` like ?"
```

```
SELECT * FROM `xxxxx`
WHERE `speakers`.`status` = ?
AND `speakers`.`id_user` != ?
AND `topiks`.`topik` LIKE ?
OR `users`.`nama` LIKE ?
```

The problem is the lack of parenthesis (`( )`) in the resulting query. It needs to be **logically grouped**. The query you want is:

```
SELECT * FROM `xxxxx`
WHERE `speakers`.`status` = ?
AND `speakers`.`id_user` != ?
AND (
    `topiks`.`topik` LIKE ?
    OR `users`.`nama` LIKE ?
)
```

The [documentation on logical grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping) has a very clear example of what you want to achieve

Applying that to your query results in the following:

```php
$list = xxxxx->where('speakers.status', '1')
             ->where('speakers.id_user', '!=', Auth::id());
        
if ($search != '' && $search != null) {
    $list = $list->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('topiks.topik', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
              ->orWhere('users.nama', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
    });
}
```

This works but you could also turn that `if` statement into a conditional clause by following the example on the [documentation on conditional clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

```php
$list = xxxxx->where('speakers.status', '1')
             ->where('speakers.id_user', '!=', Auth::id())
             ->when(($search != '' && $search != null), function ($query) use ($search) {
                 $query = $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($search) {
                     $subquery->where('topiks.topik', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                              ->orWhere('users.nama', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
                 });
             })
```

Answer (score 0):

Where can accept callback function. then you can make your logic their. Based on [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-where-clauses)

```php
$list = xxxxx->where('speakers.status', '1')
             ->where('speakers.id_user', '!=', Auth::id());
        
if ($search != '' && $search != null) {
    $list = $list->where(function($query) use ($search){
          $query->where('topiks.topik', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('users.nama', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
    });

}
```